# Why is this monic equalizer an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

What in this proof shows that the sentence in the red box below (from Mac Lane's category theory) is an isomorphism?

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $e_1se=1_v$ follows that $e_1$ is a split epimorphism.
On the other hand $e_1$ is monic, because equalizers are monic.
Thus $e_1$ is a monic split epimorphism, hence an isomorphism.

More precisely, from $e_1se=1_v$ we get $e_1see_1=e_1$ and since $e_1$ is monic, it's left-cancellable thus giving $see_1=1$.
This proves $e_1^{-1}=se$.